# PCM audio ADC: can the system clock be the fed with the PCM bit clock?

Tags: audio, digital-communications

I'm trying to use an Iridium Core 9523N module to send the speaker output of my computer over satellite to any telephone. The [integrator's guide](https://telemetry.groupcls.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Iridium-9523-9523N_Development-Guide.pdf) says it accepts PCM-formatted digital audio data, and mentions the TLV320AIC1110 as a possible source, but I find this chip more complicated than it should in this application so I've been looking for a simpler alternative.

I have come across the [PCM1808](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1808.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1703002921319&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fpcm1808) and it looks like it does the job (to me anyway...), but the datasheet shows a system clock that is also connected to the PCM master, whereas I cannot do that. I am tempted to use the BCK both for the bit clock and the system clock since apparently the only requirement is that BCK and SCKI are synchronized, but I am not sure so seeking confirmation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chip requires a system clock and it only supports a system clock that is a multiple of the sample clock.

Supported multiples are 384x, 512x, and 256x.

Comment: Thanks. Also realized the Iridium module needs 16 bits, not 24 bits frames, and the LRCLK would have been annoying since it also needs to be synchronized so it would have had to toggle every frame which is additional circuitry.

Comment: Hang on it's supporting multiples of the sampling clock, not of the bit clock - so theoretically SCKI may well be 2.048MHz while the bit clock is 256 times less. The rest still stands though

Comment: @user325962 Sorry, yes it was those multiples of the sampling rate.